# Symfony2: Referrer object similar to Request object?

Tags: php, localization, symfony

I am trying with no luck to find a "referrer" object for use in my
controller. I expected there would be an object similar to the request
object with parameters specifying the _controller, _route and
arguments.

What I am trying to do is a **language switcher** action that redirects
the user **to the same page in the new language**. Something along the
lines of:

```
public function switchLangAction($_locale)
{
    $args = array();
    $newLang = ($_locale == 'en') ? 'fr' : 'en';

    // this is how I would have hoped to get a reference to the referrer request.
    $referrer = $this->get('referrer');
    $referrerRoute = $referrer->parameters->get('_route');
    $args = $referrer->parameters->get('args'); // not sure how to get the route args out of the params either!
    $args['_locale'] = $newLang;

    $response = new RedirectResponse( $this->generateUrl(
        $referrerRoute,
        $args
    ));

    return $response;
}
```

It's also possible that there is another way to do this - I know in
rails there is the "redirect_to :back" method for example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not changing the locale in the user's session?

First, define your locales in the router

```
my_login_route:
    pattern: /lang/{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Locale:changeLang }
    requirements:
        _locale: ^en|fr$
```

Then, set the session

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LocaleController extends Controller
{
    public function switchLangAction($_locale, Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->setLocale($_locale);
        // ... some other possible actions

        return $this->redirect($session->get('referrer'));
    }
}
```

In all other controllers you should set the session variable yourself by calling

```
$session->set('referrer', $request->getRequestUri());
```

You could also probably make an event listener to set the session variable for every page automatically.

Comment: I've learned some more about Symfony2 after writing this post. A better implementation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414243/symfony2-help-please-with-backward-uri-referrer-during-switching-locale/7423276#7423276).

Answer (score 0):

It's my controller

> class LocaleController extends Controller {
>
> ```
> public function indexAction()
> {
>     if(null === $this->getRequest()->getLocale()){
>         $locale = $this->getRequest()->getPreferredLanguage($this->getLocales());
>         $this->getRequest()->setLocale($locale);
>     }
>     else{
>         $locale = $this->getRequest()->getLocale();
>     }
>
>     return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('corebundle_main_index', array('_locale' => $locale)));
> }
>
> public function changeLocaleAction($_locale)
> {
>     $request = $this->getRequest();
>     $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
>     $locales = implode('|',$this->getLocales());
>     $url = preg_replace('/\/('.$locales.')\//', '/'.$_locale.'/', $referer, 1);
>     return $this->redirect($url);
> }
>
> private function getLocales()
> {
>     return array('ru', 'uk', 'en');
> }
>
>
> /**
>  * @Template()
>  */
> public function changeLocaleTemplateAction()
> {
>     return array();
> }
> ```
>
> }