# Symfony2 language selector

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to integrate a simple HTML form allowing the user to change Symfony2 web application's language (i.e. from page en/faq go to fr/faq). How to do it in a proper way?

I have found a nice way of doing it with Symfony but not with Symfony2: http://symfony.com/blog/play-with-the-user-language

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way I have found is to do it directly in the twig template. At least, it works with 2.2:

```
<ul class="lang-menu">
  <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'ca'})) }}">Català</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: great and lightweight solution!!

Comment: dont work for me, cast error in some pages "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as such route does not exist.") " appear path dont recept the url

Comment: It works great for me. Q: where do you learn it, within the official docu (the Symfony2 book)?

Comment: @mario, I didn't found it anywhere... the idea came to me... :)

Answer (score 11):

You need to call `$this->get('session')->setLocale($locale)` (replace 'session' by 'request' for Symfony 2.1) inside your controller.

I've created a form, to which I pass an array of languages:

```
<?php
class LanguageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $langs = $options['languages'];
        $langs = array_combine($langs, $langs);
        foreach ($langs as &$lang) {
            $lang = \Locale::getDisplayName($lang);
        }

        $builder->add('language', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $langs,
            'required' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'languages' => array('fr_FR', 'en_GB'),
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_language';
    }
}
```

I submit this form to a separate action in a controller, in which I set the locale and return a redirection to last page:

```
<?php
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function switchLanguageAction()
    {
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(
            new LanguageType(),
            array('language' => $this->get('session')->getLocale()),
            array('languages' => $this->container->getParameter('roger.admin.languages', null))
        );

        $request = $this->get('request');
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $locale = $form->get('language')->getData();
            $router = $this->get('router');

            // Create URL path to pass it to matcher
            $urlParts = parse_url($referer);
            $basePath = $request->getBaseUrl();
            $path = str_replace($basePath, '', $urlParts['path']);

            // Match route and get it's arguments
            $route = $router->match($path);
            $routeAttrs = array_replace($route, array('_locale' => $locale));
            $routeName = $routeAttrs['_route'];
            unset($routeAttrs['_route']);

            // Set Locale
            $this->get('session')->setLocale($locale);

            return new RedirectResponse($router->generate($routeName, $routeAttrs));
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }
}
```

Works with any valid locale (you pass them as 'language' option while creating your form), provided that the PHP intl extension is enabled. If it's not, you'll need to replace `\Locale::getDisplayName($lang)` by a manually created list of locale names.

Comment: Just take care: the referrer may be overriden by some geeks, then `$router->match()` will throw an exception because there will be no match. A fallback could be nice here :-)

Answer (score 5):

I have not done this with a form, but simply with small flag images at the top of the screen. Each flag is a link to the current page, but with the two-letter language code in the URL replaced by the language of the respective flag. My layout template has the following code:

```
{% for language, description in languages %}
    <a href="{{ replaceLanguageInUrl(app.session.locale, language, app.request.uri) }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('images/flag_' ~ language ~ '.png') }}" alt="" title="{{ description }}"/>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

The replaceLanguageInUrl function is defined in my Twig extension class:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        'replaceLanguageInUrl' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'replaceLanguageInUrl'),
    );
}    

public function replaceLanguageInUrl($currentLanguage, $newLanguage, $url)
{

    //EDIT BEGIN
    if (strpos($url,$currentLanguage) == false) {
        $url = getBaseUrl($url).'/'.$currentLanguage;
    }
    //EDIT END
    return str_replace('/' . $currentLanguage . '/', '/' . $newLanguage . '/', $url);
}
```

When a flag is clicked, the same page is loaded, but in the new language. This will also automatically set the new language in the session.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `_locale` parameter in your routing definition automatically sets the user locale.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#the-locale-and-the-url

Comment: Yes, it is what I have done for every page, however I would like to also let the user choose the language he would like by selecting it in a list.

Answer (score 2):

I did it with the local too but something more simple than wdev's solution, i used some pictures (flags) as buttons. When the flag is clicked, the new locale is set and the page is refreshed (with a redirect) with the new language. You need to use [Symfony's translation system](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/translation.html). Here is the code:

Controller:

```
public function englishAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->get('session')->setLocale('en_US');
    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
}

public function chineseAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->get('session')->setLocale('zh_CN');
    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
}

public function frenchAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->get('session')->setLocale('fr_FR');
    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
}
```

Template:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
     <li>
           <a href="{{ path('english') }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/fkmywebsite/images/flag-en.png') }}" alt="English Language" height="30" width="18" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="{{ path('chinese') }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/fkmywebsite/images/flag-cn.jpg') }}" alt="Chinese Language" height="30" width="18" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('french') }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/fkmywebsite/images/flag-fr.png') }}" alt="French Language" height="30" width="18" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: This solution works with Symfony2.0, for Symfony2.1 check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951792/set-locale-in-symfony-2-1)