# URL of page that required login in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've got a Symfony2 site where I would like to display extra information on the Login page depending on the URL that the user is trying to access. I'm using "use_forward". Is there a way to  see the URL in the login form's controller?

I guess I could set up multiple firewalls pointing at different login pages, but there could be quite a lot of them, so I'd rather avoid having to do this.

Comment: What URL do you exactly want to display? Current? Previous (referrer)?

Comment: The current URL. The URL that has been blocked by the security config that is causing the login page to be displayed.

Comment: So, not actually the current URL, but the previous - that caused the redirect to login form?

Comment: @thecatontheflat It would be the previous URL if I wasn't using "use_forward"

Comment: I see. A bit later I'll explain you what you should overwrite to get expected behavior ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want something "proper" then look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414243/symfony2-help-please-with-backward-uri-referrer-during-switching-locale).

OR

If you want to do it quick and dirty you can use:

```
$this->container->get('request')->server->get('PHP_SELF');
```

Whick will yield something like `/project_name/web/app_dev.php/controller_name/` and you can work with that string, but take into account that it will change depending on the enviroment you are working on. The [Request class documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_get) will be your ally in this, ie:

```
$this->container->get('request')->getBasePath()
```

Will give you `/project_name/web/`

Comment: @thecatontheflat Indeed not, but gets the job done. If there is a better 'Symfony way', I'm eager to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look for this URL in some places:

```
$url = $request->get('_referer');
```

If it is empty, then you could try to check the headers

```
$url = $request->headers->get('Referer');
```